# Нужно ли обособлять сочетание "определённым образом"?

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли запятые?

1. Кот, только и делающий, что на диване лежащий, – это(,) определённым образом(,) бесполезная вещонка.

Comment: @Sharon Ещё скажите, можно ли переделывать глаголы в причастия в этом выражении (*только и делающий **то**, что на диване лежащий*).

Comment: Это фразеология.  https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/только+и+делать

Comment: @Sharon Это не фразеологизм, смысл буквальный, просто выражение. (*Только и делающий **то, что лежащий**.*)

Comment: @oleedd
Думается мне, что не все вы знаете о фразеологии...

Comment: @Sharon Знаю, что не допускаются замены слов и изменения форм. А здесь это грамматику ломает.

Comment: @oleedd Ну тогда Розенталя почитайте (пункт 9) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Comment: @oleedd Глагол не ломает грамматику, а причастие ломает. И при этом  причастие – это форма глагола.  Логично!

Comment: @Sharon Это не фразеологизм, это выражение, параграф про выражения, говорил за фразеологизмы. А выражений касается изменение формы. Так используйте причастия вместо глаголов в предложениях, раз разницы нет. Логично! Причастие — это свойство, поэтому ломает. Вторая часть не согласована с первой (инфинитив), форма во второй части меняться не будет!

Comment: The discussion is over due to the inability to continue. This is not the topic of the question. Bye-bye.

Comment: @Sharon The dumber a person is, the harder it is to prove something to him(

Comment: Are you talking about me?!

Comment: @Sharon The dumber a person is, the fewer methods and things you can use to prove. It should allude to something (from the past).

Comment: The conversation is over so it's over

Comment: Was ist denn hier passiert, als ich geschlafen habe? Lebt denn freundlich, Freunde!

Comment: Интересно сравнить: After all, what happened here while I was sleeping? Live together, friends!

Comment: Ich will nicht, dass ihr euch streiten.

Comment: Полнолуние... А так мы тихие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Кот, только и делающий, что на диване лежащий, – это, **определённым образом**, бесполезная вещонка.*

1. Запятые однозначно **нужны**,  в данном предложении это вводное сочетание **по всем показателям,** иначе и быть не может. Грамматическая структура, семантика сообщения –  всё говорит об этом.
2. **Таких вводных слов нет?** Но у нас нет и списка вводных слов. Вводные слова – это особая функция, и в значении вводных слов используются различные части речи (глаголы, частицы, наречия).
3. В заданном  предложении наречное сочетание именно **вводное.**  Вообще говоря, в языке существует ряд наречных сочетаний с подобной структурой, причем самым известным является  ***«таким образом».***
4. Есть еще вводное сочетание  **["некоторым образом"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_876),** " очень близкое по семантике к "определённым образом".

Но подобные сочетания следует отличать от **наречий**, отнесенных **к сказуемому** и  входящих в структуру предложения, например:  *Разговор их походил **некоторым образом** на сговор, а сговор ― наполовину уже заговор!*

Зачастую трудно определить, является ли такое сочетание вводным. В спорных случаях решение о расстановке знаков препинания принимает **автор** текста.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148864/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.